# Unable to remove broken mysql packages

Tags: 16.04, server, package-management, dpkg, mysql

On my server whenever I attempt to install any package I am being presented with the following error

```
Setting up mysql-common:i386 (5.7.21-1ubuntu16.04) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-client:
 mysql-community-client depends on mysql-common (>= 5.7.21-1ubuntu16.04); however:
  Package mysql-common:i386 is not configured yet.
  Version of mysql-common on system, provided by mysql-common:i386, is <none>.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client:
 mysql-client depends on mysql-community-client (= 5.7.21-1ubuntu16.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common:i386
 mysql-community-client
 mysql-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried removing mysql both with the "remove" command as well as "purge" to no avail. I've also attempted to reinstall mysql over the current broken installation and I've tried running the command "sudo apt-get -f install" which has also failed to work.

No matter what I try to do I always get a similar error about it being unable to continue due to dependency issues and I'm at a loss for what to do next.

Comment: Purge does not mean "force". But there is a --force flag, try it.

Comment: I've also tried the force flag which did not work either

Comment: Please configure with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then update with `sudo apt update` before trying to remove.

Comment: I've also tried that and it failed due to a similar error

Comment: Try `sudo touch /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback` and then `sudo dpkg --configure -a` following by `sudo apt-get install -f`. After success remove fallback file with `sudo rm /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback`.

Comment: @n0bert Thank you that fixed the issue